# How can I use Group Timeout with the Java Configuration of Aggregator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I would like to use the Aggregator Endpoint in SI to aggregate MQTT messages based on the message topic and release the aggregated message when I received all the parts (some gyroscopic values : X, Y and Z) thus far no problem... It works.
But I would like to add a group timeout so that when I don't receive all 3 values whithin a period of time the messages are discarded and I can wait for new messages.

My working code :

Configuration :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MqttListenerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MqttListenerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel filterOutputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel aggregatorOutputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory clientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setUserName("demo:application");
        options.setPassword("PwdApps".toCharArray());
        factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProducer inbound() {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("tcp://mqtt2.thingsplay.com:1883", "test-007", clientFactory(),"#");
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(1);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

Filter Endpoint :

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class MqttFilter {

    @Filter(
            inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel",
            outputChannel = "filterOutputChannel"
    )
    public boolean isValid(@Header("mqtt_receivedTopic") String topic, Message<?> message) {
        if (topic.contains("testbw")) {
            System.out.println("------ Valid Message ! ------");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Aggregator Endpoint :

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class GyroAggregator {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Aggregator(
            inputChannel = "filterOutputChannel",
            outputChannel = "aggregatorOutputChannel"
    )
    public GyroCompleted aggregate(List<Message<?>> messages) {
        GyroCompleted gyroCompleted = new GyroCompleted();
        for (Message<?> message : messages) {
            String topic = (String) message.getHeaders().get("mqtt_receivedTopic");
            if (topic.contains("ACCX")) {
                gyroCompleted.setAcc_x(Integer.valueOf((String) message.getPayload()));
            } else if (topic.contains("ACCY")) {
                gyroCompleted.setAcc_y(Integer.valueOf((String) message.getPayload()));
            } else if (topic.contains("ACCZ")) {
                gyroCompleted.setAcc_z(Integer.valueOf((String) message.getPayload()));
            }
        }
        return gyroCompleted;
    }

    @ReleaseStrategy
    public boolean hasAllAxes(List<Message<?>> messages) {
        logger.debug("In Release Strategy method.");
        logger.debug(messages);
        boolean x = false, y = false, z = false;
        for (Message<?> message : messages) {
            String topic = (String) message.getHeaders().get("mqtt_receivedTopic");
            if (topic.contains("ACCX")) {
                x = true;
            } else if (topic.contains("ACCY")) {
                y = true;
            } else if (topic.contains("ACCZ")) {
                z = true;
            }
        }
        logger.debug("Release Strategy method returning {}", x && y && z);
        return x && y && z;
    }

    @CorrelationStrategy
    public String correlateBy(@Header("mqtt_receivedTopic") String topic, Message<?> message) {
        logger.debug("In Correlation Strategy method.");
        String deviceId = topic.substring(0, topic.indexOf("/"));
        logger.debug("Correlation Strategy returning Key : {}", deviceId);
        return deviceId;
    }

}
```

Echo Endpoint :

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class EchoServiceActivator {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @ServiceActivator(
            inputChannel = "aggregatorOutputChannel"
    )
    public void echo(Message<?> message) {
        logger.debug("Echo : " + message);
    }

}
```

But for the group timeout point, I can't make it work... There is no configuration through the annotation despite the doc is saying this :

> All of the configuration options provided by the xml element are also
>   available for the @Aggregator annotation.

But a few lines below it's saying this :

> Annotation configuration (@Aggregator and others) for the Aggregator
>   component covers only simple use cases, where most default options are
>   sufficient. If you need more control over those options using
>   Annotation configuration, consider using a @Bean definition for the
>   AggregatingMessageHandler and mark its @Bean method with
>   @ServiceActivator

The problem is that I can't make that @Bean work...

[image: AggregatingMessageHandler]

I tried to put it in a class annotated with @MessageEndpoint but it won't work either. I thought that it would autowire all the component for the aggregator.

How can I make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to use the [Java DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-aggregators). Something like:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow aggregatorFlow(GyroAggregator agg) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("filterOutputChannel")
            .aggregate(a -> a
                            .processor(agg)
                            .groupTimeout(500L))
            .channel("aggregatorOutputChannel")
            .get();
}
```

Of course, you can wire the MQTT adapter and filter into the same flow.

If you want to define the handler as a `@Bean` use  `new SimpleMessageStore()` in the ctor.

Comment: Thanks it works great. But my final goal is to create an application that routes Message through different MessageChannel and thus Endpoint depending on the configuration it loads from a database and It can change at runtime... For example I got an "plugin" that aggregate 3 Mqtt Messages into one and send an alert by http. Another one would aggregate 2 Mqtt Messages and send it back on another topic on Mqtt.